# USB hub with power (and data) control

Tags: usb, power-supply, hub, power-control

Many (and fast) USB hubs are available in the market, but most of them do not provide a selective control over their single ports. From the OS, I would like to be able to:

- activate and deactivate power on each port;
- activate and deactivate data transfer on each port.

After several Google searches and as suggested in [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/66025) answer, [Yepkit](https://www.yepkit.com/home) seems to be the only one to provide a solution: [one for USB 2.0](https://www.yepkit.com/products/ykush) (even if this seems not to have data transfer control) at about 40 USD and [one for USB 3.1](https://www.yepkit.com/products/ykush) at about 90 USD.

In both cases: do some other cheaper products exist?

Comment: I suspect it will be extremely difficult or expensive to find a product that fits your specifications because of the additional cost it incurs to implement features of this nature, likely not being economical to most consumers and therefore, not in widespread circulation.